# Return Multiple TextView Values from ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a `ListView` with each column consisting of three `TextViews` (for formatting reasons).
The problem I have is when the `onItemClick` method is called I need to return the value for all three `TextViews`, which I cannot achieve using:

```
((TextView)view.).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found this worked perfectly:

```
String item = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TYPE_CELL)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning id's to the TextViews and then use findViewById to locate them in the view for the row item that was clicked. For example:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View child, int position, long id) {
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
    TextView subtitleTextView = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.textview_subtitle);
    TextView dateTextView = (TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);

    // Do the rest of your processing here
}
```

Comment: I found this to be the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Access each `TextView` in the `ListView` like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewItem, int position, long arg3) throws NullPointerException{

        TextView one = (TextView)parent.getChildAt(position-listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.tvone);
        String tvone = one.getText().toString();
        TextView two = (TextView)parent.getChildAt(position-listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.tvtwo);

        String tvtwo = two.getText().toString();
        TextView three = (TextView)parent.getChildAt(position-listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(R.id.tvthree);
        String tvthree = three.getText().toString();
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is a good answer especially passing the TextView values to  String variables